# Double vertical bar with dash through it

Tags: symbols

Is there a predefined symbol that looks like this

[image: symbol]

which is something like `\Vdash` but with the hyphen (dash) going through it?

---

Edit: I am using the following for now...

```
 \def\dplus{+\!\!\!+}
```

Comment: There is `\nparallel`, which, however, has diagonal line instead of the horizontal one.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the command I am using for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is almost OK, you just need to set the type of the symbol, avoiding two consecutive Bin symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dplus}{\mathbin{{+}\mspace{-9mu}{+}}}

\begin{document}

$a\dplus b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Act on the amount of backing up with some experiments. Here `-9mu` is the same as your `\!\!\!`.

A symbol that's as wide as the minus, with the bonus of `\tplus` with three bars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dplus}{\mathbin{\vphantom{+}\mathpalette\dpl@s{-}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tplus}{\mathbin{\vphantom{+}\mathpalette\dpl@s{+}}}
\newcommand{\rotate@minus}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\scalebox{1.09}[1]{$\m@th#1-$}}}%
}
\newcommand{\dpl@s}[2]{%
  \smash{\ooalign{$\m@th#1#2$\cr\hfil\rotate@minus{#1}\hfil\rotate@minus{#1}\hfil\cr}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$a\dplus b\tplus c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With less space between the vertical bars (but no `\tplus` in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dplus}{\mathbin{\vphantom{+}\mathpalette\dpl@s{-}}}
\newcommand{\rotate@minus}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\scalebox{1.09}[1]{$\m@th#1-$}}}%
}
\newcommand{\dpl@s}[2]{%
  \smash{\ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1#2$\cr
    \hfil\rotate@minus{#1}\hskip0pt plus 0.5fil\rotate@minus{#1}\hfil\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$a\dplus b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could use `\ooalign` to superimpose `\parallel` and the minus sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\vparallel{\mathbin{\mathpalette\@vparallel\relax}}
\newcommand*\@vparallel[2]{\ooalign{$\m@th#1\parallel$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1-$\hidewidth\cr}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$a \vparallel b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `amsmath` package is not strictly necessary for this example, but every document which contains serious math typesetting should use its features.

Answer (score 3):

All other answers think in the direction of math mode, but there is no indication that this is what OP needs.

There is the following unicode character: ỻ.

```
%%Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
ỻ
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your code I get either an error, compiling with pdfTeX or nothing at all, with XeTeX or LuaTeX. Please clarify how this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Corrected to use Junicode instead

Comment: You're welcome :) Either way, the symbol looks very different in my opinion...